# Travel documents required to travel to Nepal by a 8 year old child

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork, minors, nepal

I am an Indian national living in USA on a H1B1 visa. I will be travelling to Nepal from India, from the 13th to 18th June 2017 along with my wife and 8 year old son. Our passports will submitted to the American Embassy for visa renewal. I and my wife shall carry our voter ID cards to Nepal but what documents should my son carry? He has a valid Aadhaar card.

Answer (score 7):

As per [Bureau of Immigration](http://boi.gov.in/content/indian-passengers) (emphasis mine)

> Identity documents required for Indian Citizen going to / coming from
>   Nepal by Air :-
>
> (i) Valid National Passport.
>
> (ii) Photo Identity card issued by the
>   Government of India/State Govt./UT Administration in India to their
>   employees or **Election ID card issued by the Election Commission of
>   India.**
>
> (iii) Emergency Certificate issued by Embassy of India,
>   Kathmandu.
>
> (iv) Identity Certificate issued by Embassy of India,
>   Kathmandu.
>
> (v) **Persons in the age of group of above 65 years and below
>   15 years would be exempted from the requirement of approved identity
>   documents mentioned at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv). However,
>   they must have some documents with photograph to confirm their age and
>   identity such as PAN card, Driving license, CGHS card, Ration card
>   etc.**
>
> (vi) Children between the age group of 15 to 18 years may be
>   allowed to travel between India and Nepal on the strength of Identity
>   certificate issued by the principal of the school in the prescribed
>   performa.
>
> (vii) **In case of a family (family means husband, wife, minor
>   children and parents) traveling together, the approved identification
>   documents at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv) would not be insisted
>   from all the family members if one of the adult members of the family
>   has in possession of one of the prescribed identification documents** at
>   SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv). However, **the other family members
>   must have some proof of their identity with photograph and their
>   relationship as a family viz. CGHS card, Ration card, Driving
>   license,ID card issued by school/college etc.**
>
> Note: - **Aadhaar (UID) card is not an acceptable travel document for
>   travel to Nepal/Bhutan.**

As you are (presumably) travelling as a family, only one of you needs to have a passport or voter i-card. The rest need a valid photo ID showing status as a family (Driving License will do). Unfortunately **UID (Aadhar Card) is NOT a valid photo id proof**.

For your minor son, there are very limited options-

- Ration card - I am not sure Photo ration cards are issued anywhere
- School I-card - If you are resident in US and his school is in the US, I am not 100% sure that immigration officials will accept it.
- Passport - This is the best bet if you can defer/accelerate the renewal process