# Documents required by Indian citizens wishing to travel to Nepal

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork, nepal

I'm a citizen of India and I'm travelling to Nepal by air. Is an Aadhaar Card a valid document used for travelling to Nepal by air?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/travel-documents-required-to-travel-to-nepal-by-a-8-year-old-child/)

Comment: @RedBaron sorry; I didn't see your answer, or I would have marked this as a dupe, although the Q is a bit different.

Comment: @Dorothy no issues. That question isn't an exact dup so I didn't flag this one. The answer is almost the same though.

Answer (score 10):

No, the Aadhaar (UID) card is not acceptable. The [Indian Ministry of Home Affairs](http://boi.gov.in/content/indian-passengers) lists what can be used.

> **Identity documents required for Indian Citizen going to / coming from Nepal by Air :-**
>
> (i) Valid National Passport.
>
> (ii) Photo Identity card issued by the Government of India/State Govt./UT Administration in India to their employees or Election ID card issued by the Election Commission of India.
>
> (iii) Emergency Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu.
>
> (iv) Identity Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu.
>
> (v) Persons in the age of group of above 65 years and below 15 years would be exempted from the requirement of approved identity documents mentioned at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv). However, they must have some documents with photograph to confirm their age and identity such as PAN card, Driving license, CGHS card, Ration card etc.
>
> (vi) Children between the age group of 15 to 18 years may be allowed to travel between India and Nepal on the strength of Identity certificate issued by the principal of the school in the prescribed performa.
>
> (vii) In case of a family (family means husband, wife, minor children and parents) traveling together, the approved identification documents at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv) would not be insisted from all the family members if one of the adult members of the family has in possession of one of the prescribed identification documents at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv). However, the other family members must have some proof of their identity with photograph and their relationship as a family viz. CGHS card, Ration card, Driving license, ID card issued by school/college etc.
>
> **Note: - Aadhaar (UID) card is not an acceptable travel document for travel to Nepal/Bhutan.**

Answer (score -1):

You must carry passport or Election Card if you are flying to Kathmandu.

I faced today the shocking incident when immigration refused to check in for Del to Kathmandu.
Jet airways flight.

So sorry, I warn all the Indian citizen to do not make such mistake.

Thank you

Comment: The other answer, which quotes the Indian Ministry of Home Affairs, says that various other forms of ID are actually accepted, and not just passports and election cards. So this answer appears to be incorrect. Or is the quoted text in the other answer out of date or something?