# What documents are needed to travel by air from Nepal to India?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, nepal, identity-cards

I have Indian nationality. I'm in Nepal with my family (wife and 3 children) for vacation.

We want to go home to Mumbai, but couldn't get train tickets, so we decided to go by air.

My wife and I have Pan and Aadhaar cards, my 3 children have Aadhaar cards​.

Can we use these to travel by air from Nepal to Mumbai?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documents required by Indian citizens wishing to travel to Nepal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89272/documents-required-by-indian-citizens-wishing-to-travel-to-nepal)

Comment: @Dorothy the proposed dupe is about traveling *to* Nepal, not *from* Nepal to India.

Comment: I think this link would be helpful to you : http://boi.gov.in/content/indian-passengers

Comment: @JonathanReez it should cover it, as the gov't info refers to air travel both to and from Nepal.

Answer (score 2):

The [Government of India Bureau of Immigration](http://boi.gov.in/content/indian-passengers) specifies that

> Even for re-entry into the country, an Indian national is required to be in possession of a valid Indian passport or travel document issued by Govt. of India.
>
> **Identity documents required for Indian Citizen coming from Nepal by Air:**
>
> (i) Valid National Passport.
>
> (ii) Photo Identity card issued by the Government of India/State Govt./UT Administration in India to their employees or Election ID card issued by the Election Commission of India.
>
> (iii) Emergency Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu.
>
> (iv) Identity Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu.
>
> (v) Persons in the age of group of above 65 years and below 15 years would be exempted from the requirement of approved identity documents mentioned at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv). However, they must have some documents with photograph to confirm their age and identity such as PAN card, Driving license, CGHS card, Ration card etc.
>
> (vi) Children between the age group of 15 to 18 years may be allowed to travel between India and Nepal on the strength of Identity certificate issued by the principal of the school in the prescribed performa.
>
> (vii) In case of a family (family means husband, wife, minor children and parents) traveling together, the approved identification documents at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv) would not be insisted from all the family members if one of the adult members of the family has in possession of one of the prescribed identification documents at SL. No. (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv). However, the other family members must have some proof of their identity with photograph and their relationship as a family viz. CGHS card, Ration card, Driving license, ID card issued by school/college etc.
>
> Note: - Aadhaar (UID) card is not an acceptable travel document for travel to Nepal/Bhutan.

Answer (score -2):

**Indian nationals do not require a visa to enter India from Nepal**. As per the Nepalese Immigration, Indian nationals travelling from Nepal must possess any of the following documents:

1. Passport.
2. Driving license with photo.
3. Photo identity card issued by a Government Agency.
4. Ration card with photo.
5. Election Commission Card with a photo.
6. Identity Card issued by the Embassy of India in Kathmandu.
7. Identity Card with photo issued by a Sub- Divisional Magistrate or any other official above this rank.

Comment: You have it reversed: the question is about traveling _to_ India _from_ Nepal.